# How can i Fix this error when creating a chatbot?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

am running my train_chatbot.py script but its throwing an error
train_chatbot.py:72: VisibleDeprecationWArning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of list-or-tuples-or ndarray with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. if you meant to do this, you must specify 'd-type=object'when creating the ndarray training = np.array(training)
what could be the problem i gave tried the solutions in tensor flow throwing error but its not helping.
i am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Note that this isn't an error, it is a warning. Specifically a deprecation warning (unless this is just misnamed and is actually causing an error). It tells you exactly how to fix it in the message, but it is also possible you have set up your sequences improperly. Without your code we can't help any further.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve] including code, sample input, and the full traceback of any errors, so that we can better understand how to help